# How to update a record in a Django model using forms?

Tags: python, django, database

I am new to Django and need some help.

I am basically trying to build a Tinder-like application for movies using Django and working on the basics of the 'swiping' functionality. And, while using a form I am having trouble getting the swipe input. I only want a boolean value from the user (true for yes and false for no) and for this to get updated according to the movie id in the database. But I am unable to perform this updation. My form adds a new record instead.

Perhaps an easier alternative would be to remove the swipes field from the model entirely , just use it as a variable and maintain a list of movies where this variable was selected to be true. I was unable to access the movie id in this case so this failed too ;-;

How do I get this working in a simple efficient manner?

Here is what my models.py looks like:

```
class Movie(models.Model):

    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=300) # unique id for room
    movie_description = models.TextField(default='')
    movie_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movie_date_released = models.DateField(null=True)
    movie_swiped = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    
    # Override the __str__ method to return the firstname and lastname
    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie_name

    def is_exists(self):
        ''' Check whether a user exists in the database '''
        if Movie.objects.get(movie_name=self.movie_name): 
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

views.py

```
# Create your views here.

class RoomSwipeView(APIView):

    # Define a class variables 
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    queryset = []
    swiped_movies=[]

    def get(self, request):

        # Get the room id from the request
        movie_id = request.GET.get('id')
        
        if movie_id: 
            queryset = Movie.objects.filter(id=movie_id)

        else: 
            queryset = Movie.objects.all()
        
        print(queryset)
        print("BRUHHHH")
        
        form = MovieSwipeForm
        
        return render(request,'swipe.html',{'details':queryset, 'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = MovieSwipeForm(request.POST)
        submitted = False
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                print("Getting here!!!!!!!")
                swiped = form.save(commit=False)
                if(swiped.movie_swiped):
                    swiped_movies.push(swiped)
                    print(swiped_movies)
        else:
            form = MovieSwipeForm
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True

        return render(request,'swipe.html',{'details':queryset, 'form':form,'submitted':submitted})
```

Another issue in this file is that the `swiped_movies` and `queryset` class variables are not being accessed by the post method and that throws an error too.

swipe.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Movie Details</h1>
        {% for obj in details %}
        {{obj.movie_name}}<br/>
        Description: {{obj.movie_description}}<br/>
        Genre: {{obj.movie_genre}}<br/>
        Date Released: {{obj.movie_date_released}}<br/>
        <!-- <button type="button">YES</button>
        <button type="button">NO</button> -->
        {% if submitted %}
            Success
        {% else %}
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <!-- <input type="submit" value="NO"> -->

            </form>
        {% endif %}
        <br/><br/>       
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
class MovieSwipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('movie_swiped',)
```

Comment: kindly elaborate how you're trying to mark movies as *swiped* also there is not variable with the name `movies_swiped `

Comment: Oops, typo. I meant to say ```swiped_movies```. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass instance of movie object which you want to update it to form when initiate the form, thereby an existence object will be updated,  otherwise form.save() will create new object instead

In view.py

```
Instance = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)

form = MovieSwipeForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

To access class parameters in the class, you need to call them self.parameter so to access queryset in post method use self.queryset